# How do I get a numbered list to have a therefore sign in front of the last element?

Tags: enumerate

[image]

Hi all, I want to write out an argument with numbered premises in which there is a therefore sign in front of the conclusion, but the number corresponding to the conclusion is aligned with the previous numbers (see attached image). Is there a way to do this in the enumerate environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you want LaTeX to find out if the item is the last one, you could do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\ThereForeLeft}{\makebox[0pt][r]{$\therefore$\ifnum\value{enumi}<10
\hspace{0.85cm}%
\else
\hspace{1.2cm}%
\fi}}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\arabic{enumi})}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item Blah
 \item Blub
 \item\ThereForeLeft Blubber
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Since the `\therefore` is only used in the last item, there is no problem in redefining a macro at that point.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,amssymb,etoolbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newlist{modusponens}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[modusponens]{label=\maybetherefore(\arabic*),ref=(\arabic*)}

\newrobustcmd{\maybetherefore}{}
\newcommand{\lastitem}{\renewrobustcmd\maybetherefore{\makebox[0pt][r]{$\therefore$ }}\item}

\begin{document}

\begin{modusponens}
\item If Halep is \SI{174.7}{cm} and William is \SI{175}{cm}, then William is taller than Halep.
\item Halep is \SI{174.7}{cm} and William is \SI{175}{cm}.
\lasttitem William is taller than Halep.
\end{modusponens}

\end{document}
```

The redefinition will disappear at `\end{modusponens}`, so no `\therefore` will appear in front of the items in the next `modusponens` environment (it would in items following `\lastitem` in the same `modusponens` environment).

[image]

With some trickery, you can avoid `\lastitem`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,amssymb,etoolbox,refcount}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newlist{modusponens}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[modusponens]{
  label=\maybetherefore(\arabic*),
  ref=\arabic*,
  before=\stepcounter{modusponens},
  after=\addtocounter{modusponensi}{-1}\refstepcounter{modusponensi}\label{\themodusponens},
}
\newcounter{modusponens}

\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd{\maybetherefore}{%
  \edef\temp{\getrefnumber{\themodusponens}}%
  \edef\temp{\expandafter\@firstofone\temp}%
  \ifnum\temp=\value{modusponensi}%
    \makebox[0pt][r]{$\therefore$ }%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{modusponens}
\item If Halep is \SI{174.7}{cm} and William is \SI{175}{cm}, then William is taller than Halep.
\item Halep is \SI{174.7}{cm} and William is \SI{175}{cm}.
\item William is taller than Halep.
\end{modusponens}

\end{document}
```

At the end of the environment, we issue a `\label` that will reference the last item number. Now `\maybetherefore` checks whether the item number matches the last.

This may require two LaTeX runs, if other `modusponens` environments have been added.

If there are *always* three items, it's much simpler:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,amssymb,etoolbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newlist{modusponens}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[modusponens]{
  label=\maybetherefore(\arabic*),
  ref=\arabic*,
}

\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd{\maybetherefore}{%
  \ifnum 3=\value{modusponensi}%
    \makebox[0pt][r]{$\therefore$ }%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{modusponens}
\item If Halep is \SI{174.7}{cm} and William is \SI{175}{cm}, then William is taller than Halep.
\item Halep is \SI{174.7}{cm} and William is \SI{175}{cm}.
\item William is taller than Halep.
\end{modusponens}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try (by hand)  `\item[\llap{$\therefore$\ }(3)]`.

Comment: Why this downvote?

Comment: There is not a downvote now. Your answer is correct.

Comment: Thanks, @Sebastiano!